# Error when using library in .NET Framework 4.7.2 and everything works in .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, dll, frameworks

There is a third party library that needs to be used.

- When used in .NET 5.0 (ended) everything works.
- When used in .NET Framework 4.7.2, nothing works.

An error occurs in the following piece of code:

```
var addr = WinApi.LoadLibraryW(path);

if (addr == IntPtr.Zero)
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to load library \"{path}\": {WinApi.GetLastError()}");
```

Error text:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Failed to load library "D:\Project\Project\bin\Debug\x64\lib.dll": 0"

Class with method:

```
internal class WinApi
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "LoadLibraryW")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryW(string dllToLoad);
}
```

Comment: I see the error code is just 0, that sucks.  Off hand I'd say make sure your .Net app is built as 64 bit.  You can't load a dll that is different bitness than the app.

Comment: @bmiller Indeed, my application is launched as 32bit, tomorrow I will try to change the configuration and run it.

Comment: Why not just got to .NET 6 instead reverting back to .net Framework?

Comment: @bmiller It works on 64 bit, but some library from 32 bit are not working, lol. Luckily, I managed to find a 32-bit version of the library. The issue was resolved, albeit in this way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Because old projects are written on .NET Framework :-(